# How to speed up Rust clone method in my custom struct?

Tags: python, rust, struct, clone, pyo3

I have struct in Rust with following fields and their types:

- five i8
- six f32
- one bool
- one Vec of size 4
- one Vec<Vec<Vec>> of size 4x20x7
- one Vec<Vec> of size 4x20
- one HashMap<i8, Vec> with 4 keyes
- one Vec<(i8, i8)> of size varing from 0 to 30

My question is how to speed up cloning of object of this structure?
Now I'm using just

```
fn py_make_copy(&self) -> PyResult<Self> {
    Ok(self.clone())
}
```

and it takes from 4 to 6 µs and it is to slow for me. I was measuring it in Python.
Unfortunately I have to deepcopy those objects.

I don't know if it is releveant but I use

```
#[pyclass(subclass)]
#[derive(Clone)]
```

when defining this Struct and #[pyo3(get)] to all of the fields.

I tried to parallelize cloning with par_iter but it lasted much longer than py_make_copy.

Comment: That's quite a lot of heap allocations. Maybe using arrays or something like tinyvec would help.

Comment: If you don't need or want deep copies for some or all of your objects, there's `Arc` or `Rc` to *share* ownership (so a copy is just an increment).

Comment: However, if this is used in a Python+Rust interface and 6us is too slow (and thus you're probably calling this a lot), consider crafting your API so objects move cross the boundary less often and you process things on the Rust side in-bulk if at all possible.

Comment: I think you will already be a lot faster if you transform `Vec<Vec<Vec>>` of size `4x20x7` into a single `Vec` of size `560`. In its current state, it contains `4x20 = 80`!! heap allocations.

Comment: Also small tip: Questions that say "how can I speed up" or similar are sooo much easier and better to answer if they contain a [MRE]. Maybe consider adding one.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to reproduce your claims, and this is what I got:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, hint::black_box, time::Instant};

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub five_i8: [u8; 5],
    pub six_f32: [f32; 6],
    pub one_bool: bool,
    pub vec1: Vec<u8>,
    pub vec2: Vec<Vec<Vec<u8>>>,
    pub vec3: Vec<Vec<u8>>,
    pub hashmap: HashMap<i8, Vec<u8>>,
    pub vec4: Vec<(i8, i8)>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct {
        five_i8: [42u8; 5],
        six_f32: [69.420; 6],
        one_bool: true,
        vec1: vec![42u8; 4],
        vec2: Default::default(),
        vec3: Default::default(),
        hashmap: Default::default(),
        vec4: vec![(1i8, 2i8); 30],
    };

    for i in 0..4 {
        let mut x = vec![];
        for _ in 0..20 {
            x.push(vec![1u8; 7]);
        }

        s.vec2.push(x);
        s.vec3.push(vec![42u8; 20]);
        s.hashmap.insert(i, vec![2u8; 10]);
    }

    // Blackbox to prevent optimization
    let s = black_box(s);

    let start = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..10000 {
        let s2 = s.clone();
        black_box(s2);
    }
    let elapsed = start.elapsed();

    println!("Time: {} us", elapsed.as_micros() / 10000);
}
```

```
$ cargo run --release
Time: 17 us
```

Now why is that so slow? The answer is: Heap allocations. Everything else is very fast.

The only thing in your struct that performs heap allocations are the `HashMap` and the `Vec`. Each `Vec` and `HashMap` is one heap allocation.

So let's see:

- `vec1`: `1` allocation
- `vec2`: `1 + 4 * (1 + 20) = 85` allocations
- `vec3`: `1 + 4 = 5` allocations
- `hashmap`: `1 + 4 = 5` allocations
- `vec4`: `1` allocation

That's a total of `97` allocations.

The easiest way is to change the `Vec<Vec<Vec<>>>` to a single, flattened `Vec`. This would reduce `vec2` and `vec3` down to a single allocation, and the total count down to `9` allocations.

Like this:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, hint::black_box, time::Instant};

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub five_i8: [u8; 5],
    pub six_f32: [f32; 6],
    pub one_bool: bool,
    pub vec1: Vec<u8>,
    pub vec2: Vec<u8>,
    pub vec3: Vec<u8>,
    pub hashmap: HashMap<i8, Vec<u8>>,
    pub vec4: Vec<(i8, i8)>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct {
        five_i8: [42u8; 5],
        six_f32: [69.420; 6],
        one_bool: true,
        vec1: vec![42u8; 4],
        vec2: vec![10u8; 560],
        vec3: vec![42u8; 80],
        hashmap: Default::default(),
        vec4: vec![(1i8, 2i8); 30],
    };

    for i in 0..4 {
        s.hashmap.insert(i, vec![2u8; 10]);
    }

    // Blackbox to prevent optimization
    let s = black_box(s);

    let start = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..10000 {
        let s2 = s.clone();
        black_box(s2);
    }
    let elapsed = start.elapsed();

    println!("Time: {} us", elapsed.as_micros() / 10000);
}
```

```
$ cargo run --release
Time: 1 us
```